# Master Page Public property not available in Content Page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I'm trying to access a master page property from content page so that I can set a literal on master page file easily. So I created the master page property this way in Masterpage vb file

```
    Public Property PropertyOnMasterPage() As String
    Get
        ' Get value of control on master page
        Return ltr_companyname.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ' Set new value for control on master page
        ltr_companyname.Text = value
    End Set
    End Property
```

But I've no idea how can I get or set this property from content page.(based [on this tutorial](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Master-page-Content-Page-Interaction.aspx)).
Thats in C#. But when I tried Master. intellisense not showing that master page property. So how can I get the master page property on contetn page. Do it required to refer anything on the content page?

**EDIT**

These are master page and content page screenshot.. In the content page screenshot, you can see intellisense not finding that property

Content Page
[image]

Master page
[image]

Comment: what about this.Master

Comment: in VB.NET - the equvivalent of C#'s `this.` is `Me.` - try that and see if you can access the master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that you need to set the [`MasterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274(v=vs.85).aspx) from the content page so that it will know what class the master page is. Then it will be strongly typed and there will be no need to cast it.

Put this below your `@ Page` directive, obviously with the correct path to your master page.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# You can Use this.Master to Access the page Master page
I think You should have Me.Master

so In content page you would end up like this

```
Me.Master.PropertyOnMasterPage
```

Comment: This will only work if the MasterType directive is set properly on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had luck with strong typing reference to the master page, so what I normally do is create an interface:

```
Public Interface IMyMaster
    Property PropertyOnMasterPage As String
End Interface
```

On your master page file, implement it:

```
Public Class SiteMaster
    Inherits MasterPage
    Implements IMyMaster

    Public Property PropertyOnMasterPage As String Implements IMyMaster.PropertyOnMasterPage

End Class
```

And then convert the Me.Master reference to the interface, and access the property like:

```
CTYpe(Me.Master, IMyMaster).PropertyOnMasterPage
```

The interface adds a looser coupling (sort of) anyway.

Comment: The images are blocked (proxy), but either way, intellisense only works with a strongly-typed master page.  I've had issues with that (worked sometimes, not others), but if you use the technique above, it will work fine.